# Connecting my iphone to my raspberry pi4 (Raspberry Pi OS)

Tags: security, ip

I would like to connect to my pi4 via my iphone so I can view my security camera outside of my home network.
Currently my pi4 is accessible via a fixed ip address but there is no security assigned to it.

What options do I have to allow access only from my iphone and/or my laptop?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a static IP adress, or DynDNS set up? Are you simply port forwarding to your Pi?

Comment: I have port forwarded it to a static ip address if thats the correct way of saying it. So yes I am port forwarding

Comment: Hope it isn't a well-known port (one less than 1024).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if your raspberry pi is reachable from internet facing ports and you've not set up the proper security (like private key authentication, a strong password, and a firewall), disable port forwarding IMMEDIATELY.

If you want to provide secure access to your network from the internet, you can set up a VPN. You could run a VPN server either directly on your raspberry pi (check out PiVPN), or you could use another machine. After setting up a VPN and configuring a VPN client on your phone and laptop, you will be able to access machines on your home network from anywhere you have an internet connection. Most importantly, you can configure the VPN for private key authentication, so that you're the only one who can access your home network on the VPN.

Comment: many thanks for your tips. Is what you suggested a different mechanism to using fail2ban? I have tried using this tool by banning all ips except 2 (my iphone and laptop). Unfortunately my pi4 is still accessible from the internet (outside of my home network)

Comment: Yes, this is different. Your external IP on your phone and the external IP you have on your laptop will change frequently. So banning all IPs except a couple might work for a short amount of time, but eventually when your IP changed, you'd get locked out and you'd have to change your fail2ban configuration.

Comment: I have set up RPi recommended security protocols on my pi4 and also installed VNC as host and VNC as client on the laptop and iphone. So now I can only access pi4 via VNC over the internet. Good. Problem I have now is the port forwarding is not working with my acquired fixed ip. I assigned tcp http with open port 5900 (checked via canyouseeme.org). Not sure how to investigate

Comment: @user9106985 If you have a follow-up question, please post it as new question and add a link to this question to establish context. Also, since the present answer seems to have solved your original problem, please consider [accepting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so that others facing a similar issue may find it more easily.